# Grunt config - dynamic mapping

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have the following in my Gruntfile.coffee:

```
    jade:
        options:
            data:
                debug: false
        firstLevel:
            files: [
                expand: true
                flatten: true
                cwd: '<%= srcDir %>/documents/'
                src: ["*.jade"]
                dest: "<%= outDir %>"
                ext: ".html"
            ]
        subLevel:
            files: [
                expand: true
                flatten: true
                cwd: '<%= srcDir %>/documents'
                src: ["/<%= subFolder %>/*.jade"]
                dest: "<%= outDir %>/<%= subFolder %>"
                ext: ".html"
            ]
```

The firstLevel part is compiling properly, but the subLevel is not matching anything.
I have a file structure like this:

```
project
  -src
    -posts
    -pages
    ...
    index.jade
  -our
```

I would like to render every sub folder in the src folder.
I read [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks) that I could use placeholders in Underscore's style, and then I don't have to specify every folder statically.

What is wrong with my code, how could I fix this to work with sub folders?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? `grunt-jade` or `grunt-contrib-jade`?

Comment: Also, where did you define `subFolder`?

Comment: @Dancrumb: I use grunt-contrib-jade.
And maybe I misunderstood this part, I tought it will define the subFolder variable, to reuse in the line after. So I want to place `src/pages/about.jade` to `out/pages/about.html`.
If I don't use flatten, it will be like: `out/src/pages/about.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to copy everything from

```
src/XXX/XXX.jade
```

to

```
out/XXX/XXX.html
```

then use

```
files: [
           {
              expand: true,
              cwd: "<%= srcDir %>/",
              src: "**/*.jade",
              dest: "<%= outDir %>/",
              ext: ".html"
           }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks, now I don't need two levels, and stuff... That's pretty simple. I appreciate!